# $http post and get in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning AngularJS at the moment
and I'm trying to create something with the $http service
and everytime i send my data throw it either as post or get 
the server side (PHP) tells me it's an empty data (NULL)
here is my code so far.
I would like to know why it's always receiving an empty string of data as well as does Angular code the data that is sent as json or normal data attribute like in PHP => (name=ahmed&job=student)

## Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('AddArticle', []);
app.controller("AddArticlesController", function($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    $scope.SubmitData = function() {

        $http({
            url: 'Inc/newArticle.php',
            method: 'POST',
            params: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({ArticleSubject: $scope.ArticleSubject, ArticleContent: $scope.ArticleContent}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data == "yes") {
                $scope.show = "Sent";
            } else {
                alert(response.data);
            }
        }, function(response) {
            alert("failed php");
        });
    };
});
```

note that the following PHP code works fine without any problems when you send it a data from a regular form, Ajax or JQuery Ajax

## newArticle.php

```
    <?php 
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "HardWork Results/AngularJS/Inc/functions.php";
// the following two echo are for testing onle
        echo $_POST["ArticleSubject"];
        echo $_POST["ArticleContent"];
        $Subject = htmlspecialchars($_GET["ArticleSubject"]);
        $Content = htmlspecialchars($_GET["ArticleContent"]);
        if (empty($Subject)) {
            echo "Subject is null";
        }
        if (empty($Content)) {
            echo "Content is null";
        }
        if (!empty($Subject) && !empty($Content)) {
            if (AddArticle($Subject, $Content) ) {
                echo "yes";
            } else {
                echo "no";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

## index.html

```
<div class="Article" data-ng-app="AddArticle" data-ng-controller="AddArticlesController">
    <form name="Articles" method="post" data-ng-submit="SubmitData()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Article Subject: </label>
            <input type="text" required id="ArticleSubject" name="ArticleSubject" placeholder="ex: Moussa is shitty TA" data-ng-model="ArticleSubject" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Article Content: </label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" required id="ArticleContent" name="ArticleContent" placeholder="ex: We know Moussa is Awesome, have fun and enjoy life" data-ng-model="ArticleContent"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit" data-ng-click="SubmitData()" data-ng-init="show='Send'">{{ show }}</button>
    </form>
    <div class="ArticleDesign">
        <h1 data-ng-bind="ArticleSubject"></h1>
        <p data-ng-bind="ArticleContent"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the main problem is that you've got a form that's doing a submit against a PHP script on the back end, but you're trying to use angular.  My guess would be that the form action happens before angular does its thing.  If you're working with Angular, you don't want to do form submissions.  Angular always wants to talk to the server with AJAX and JSON.

Comment: I see, I will change it right now and let you know what happens

Comment: Nothing wrong with using form. Change from button click to `ng-submit`. Remove action from form. Also note default expected response is json

Comment: I've tried removing the form tag completely but nothing worked (same problem)  
and I did as you said as well and added the ng-submit as suggested but nothing worked at well (same problem)

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate on ''default expected response is json''